# Java and MySQL query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have problem with java and MySQL. My code:

```
Connection connection;
// ...
for (String query : updateAndInsertQuery) {
   Statement stm = connection.createStatement();
   stm.execute(query);
   stm.close();
}


Statement stm2 = connection.createStatement();
System.out.println("Before query");
System.out.flush();
ResultSet Result = stm2.executeQuery(selectQuery);
System.out.println("After query");
System.out.flush();
int vfrom, vto;
while (Result.next()) {
    // ... 
}
```

When I run program i see in MySQL queries and run

```
show processlist;
```

`selectQuery` is visible on list wth status Sending data or Writing to net. On console print: `Before query`. Next

```
show processlist;
```

returns empty list, but application don't print `After query`. Do you have similar problem?

-- edit

I resolve my problem.

I think:
wen MySQL returns data and query isn't visible on processlist in MySQL 
I should immediately get on console message: After query

but console was empty, java process works (cpu usage was 90-100%) so I think it was my mistake, but after 1h application throws Exception

Increase memory limit resolve my problem.

So I have next question why application throw exception after hour? Garbage collection try dealocate unised objects?

Comment: What happens to the application, does it crash or freeze? Could you explain your steps in more detail?

Comment: There's probably an exception. What is the query?

Comment: Can you tell what is the value of `selectQuery`?

Answer (score -5):

executing queries manually usually leads into many different problems - all of which are platform-specific and DB-specific. I think your best answer will be : "switch to ORM".

This framework has proven to be exceptionally good, wrappig all your SQL-data into Entities and transactions (if required) will resolve most of your problems at the same time - you will only need to annotate your entities and relationships correctly. Database-queries can be executed via JPA-"criteria"s which are platform-independent AND allow you to avoid a lot of problems as well as making your code READABLE.

Tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html
SO-question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743065/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-learn-jpa

With JPA, you wont need to care about statements or queries anymore (well, at least most of the time) and your mentioned problem will disappear - PLUS : it only takes 30-60min to implement.

Additional tip : use Maven & Eclipselink (JPA2 implementation) - thats a very powerful, portable combination

Comment: Thank you, but I think that I don't need ORM in this case.

Comment: In this specific case probably i don't need orm. I construct large graph in memory, create temporary tables in database so probably I don't need orm in this case.

Comment: apparently quite a few internet superheros dont like ORM ... its probably too complex for them :-)